# $PATH problem in 16.04 "WARNING: your PATH doesn't contain ..."

Tags: command-line, bash, 16.04, paths

I use ubuntu 16.04 and trying to install a simulator (Omnet++).
When I try and configure, it gives the below warning:

```
WARNING: your PATH doesn't contain /home/aboubakar/omnetpp-5.0/bin!
Add the following line to your .profile or .bash_profile (provided you use bash):

    export PATH=$PATH:/home/aboubakar/omnetpp-5.0/bin
```

But I already add that to : `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`

The output of echo $PATH:
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/aboubakar/omnetpp-5.0/bin:/opt/google_appengine/:/home/aboubakar/omnetpp-4.6/bin`

Comment: Add output of `echo "$PATH"` to your question.

Comment: the warning says, you should use `.bash_profile`, not `.bashrc`. Also note, that you should log-out and in again after the change.

Comment: You don't have to log out and log in again after the change, just run `source <changedFile>`.

Comment: I have have use .profile because I don't have file .bash_profile but the warming still present

Comment: After making changes to .bash_profile or .bashrc you have to exit the terminal and start again, or use "source .bashrc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution that finally worked for me in 16.04 was to add the command to `/etc/profile`, so `sudo nano /etc/profile` and then at the bottom add

`export PATH=$PATH:/home/aboubakar/omnetpp-5.0/bin`

save and exit and then

`source /etc/profile`

@Volcan300 after doing this, if you `sudo su` your are correct the variables won't be applied.  However if you

1. Log in is a root they will be applied

or

2. Call `source /etc/profile` after `sudo su` with will also be applied.

Answer (score 1):

When you do sudo ./configure, the user that needs to have the PATH address is the sudo user. When you edit the .profile, the user is not necessarily the sudo user. Try it:

```
$sudo su
$. setenv
$ echo $PATH #(here you can see the $PATH with the address)
```

then

```
$ sudo ./configure
```

I have exactly the same problem.